# Measurement in realtime Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, python, real-time

I have written a script in python in my Raspberry Pi 3, to get and plot data in real-time from an ADC.

The problem is that the data is not time accurate. I want my data to be read once per second or with a delay of one second each. Is there any software method in Raspberry Pi 3, or should I get extra clock and get it with ADC together?

A part of the code

```
def value_adc(): 
    startmess = time.process_time() 
    ADC = ADS1256.ADS1256()
    ADC.ADS1256_init()
    ADC_Value = ADC.ADS1256_GetAll()
    volt = [(ADC_Value[0]*5.0)]
    
    diffrence = time.process_time()-startmess
    if diffrence < 0.1:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(raspi)
        curs = conn.cursor()
        write = curs.execute("INSERT INTO poti values(datetime('now'), (?))", (volt))
        conn.commit()
        pause.seconds(1-diffrence)
        return write
        return conn.commit() 
    else: 
        print(datetime.datetime.now())
```

I have tried to pause for *(1 sec - the run time of the code)* but I still sometimes get more than one data per secound, and sometime a delay of more than a secound.

Comment: Do you have to re-initialize the ADC for every reading? Wouldn't it be  better to initialize it outside this function, and then pass it in or access it as a class member or global?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the real system time not the process_time (cpu time).

I have a class which helps me schedule tasks like this.  I create a stopwatch then start it,  I keep checking the elapsed time using the elapsed() or elapsed_ms() method and when it returns a value greater than the interval I want I execute the task I need to run and then call start on the stopwatch again.

import time

class StopWatch:

```
"""
a class which performs timing
"""

def __init__(self):
    """Initialize a new `Stopwatch`, but do not start timing."""
    self.start_time = None
    self.stop_time = None

def start(self):
    """Start timing."""
    self.start_time = time.time()

def stop(self):
    """Stop timing."""
    self.stop_time = time.time()

def elapsed(self) -> int:
    """Return the number of seconds that have elapsed since this
    `Stopwatch` started timing.
    This is used for checking how much time has elapsed while the timer is
    still running.
    """
    if self.start_time:
        return int(time.time() - self.start_time)
    return 0

def elapsed_ms(self) -> int:
    """Return the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since this
    `Stopwatch` started timing.
    This is used for checking how much time has elapsed while the timer is
    still running.
    """
    if self.start_time:
        return int((time.time() - self.start_time) * 1000)
    return 0
```